# Calculated column to show status if another has a value

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date-time

I have a SharePoint list with a completed date column. I wish to have a calculated column called status so when the completed date column has a date in it, it shows "Closed" and when it is blank it shows "Open".

Can anyone help me with the formula for this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using below formula, it will work for you:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([completed date]),"Open","Closed")
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Return your calculated field as **Single line of text**.

**Example**:

**Column Settings**:

[image]

**Output**:

[image]

**official documentation**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)).

Comment: Thank you, the top one worked perfectly :-)

Comment: Welcome. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you.

Comment: Will do :-) Can I ask how do I make the Open in Red and the Closed in Green?

Comment: If you are using modern experience then you can use Column/JSON formatting to achieve this. You can check the examples [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#apply-conditional-formatting) or ask a new question so that I can answer on it with complete explanation and code.

Answer (score 4):

try the below formula, add the below formula in the status - calculated column

```
=IF( ISBLANK([completed]) , "Open" , "Closed" )
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked a treat

Comment: Can I ask how do I make the Open in Red and the Closed in Green?

Comment: You should ask this as a separate question, but anyways, you can use column formatting, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting